# ember store is undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Here are the main code lines of my ember application :

```
/** Initialization and configuration */
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
```

and :

```
App.GenerationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
actions: {
    generation: function(){
        var graph = this.store.find('graph', 1);
        [...]
    }
}
```

When my action is launched, I have this in my console : `TypeError: this.store is undefined`

Can someone help me to fix it ? And moreover, to understand why the store seems not accessible from a controller ?

Thanks

Comment: Does `this.get('store')` returns something?

Comment: Also what is your ember and ember-data versions?

Comment: wow, ```this.get('store')``` works fine !
Do you have a link about this fix ? How does it works ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're welcome! `Ember.Object` is the base class of some ember classes, like `Ember.Route`, `Ember.Controller`, `Ember.View` and so on. And in order to access these properties you should use `this.get('prop')` and `this.set('prop', value)`, instead of `this.prop` or `this.prop = value`. This is mainly needed to give support for two way databinding, computed properties and others things for older browsers like ie8. You can find more info in the Ember.Object [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of Ember the store was available only as a computed property, so it had to be accessed as such:

```
this.get('store') // set and get handle asynchrony for us
```

Now, the store is setup as a service during app initialization. This guarantees that the store is already setup by the time your app logic begins executing and allows you to do:

```
this.store
```

So, you are using an old Ember version.

Comment: That's true, I updated my bower.json and now I can use this.store !
Thanks a lot for the explanation :)